# Why doesn't a link to a local word document work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm viewing in Internet Explorer 8.

I have a link to a local file (a href = "file:///path). I know the path is correct because if I copy it and paste it in a new window, it opens fine. But when I click the link, nothing at all happens. (I can also save a copy by right clicking the link and "Save Target As")

These types of links work fine if I just open the page from My Computer in Internet Explorer, but do not work when I try to hit them over localhost. I have localhost set as Local Intranet in security settings.

Do these links just not work in IE anymore, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It is a security setting. Normally web pages cannot link to local files in any way at all. This is because they could use hidden form parts such as upload to upload any file from your hard drive. You may be able to lower Internet Security in Options.

Edit: What happens if you drag the file from Explorer to the address bar?

Comment: The what now? Links are hardly the same thing as file inputs...

Comment: @SamB Yep, I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's the new windows updates on Windows 7. I have old HTML files on my Windows7 computer that still work this way.

But if I copy the exact code into a new text doc on Windows 7 and then rename to `.html` they do not work.

My advise is to create your work on another computer with, say, XP installed. Then move to Windows 7 and then they will work. Or keep copying an old version of an HTML doc that works and edit / rename after.

Comment: But, what's the problem?